# Normal subgroups and isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm supposed to prove that if a group $K$ has normal subgroups $G$ and $H$ with $G \cup H = 1$ and $G \vee H = K$ then there is an isomorphism $\Theta: G \times H \cong K$ defined by $\Theta (g, h) = gh$ for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ and so elsewhere I've got this theorem that says that if a group $K$ has subgroups $G$ and $H$ with $G \cup H = 1$ and $G \vee H = K$ then there is an isomorphism $\Theta: G \times H \cong K$ defined by $\Theta (g, h) = gh$ for all $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ as long as $gh = hg$ for $g \in G, h \in H$ so I'm guessing here that what I have to do is show that if $G$ and $H$ are normal subgroups of $K$ then $gh = hg$ for $g \in G, h \in H$. This is not apparent, and it's kind of killing me. Any help y'all could offer would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you meant $\,G\cap H = 1\,$ in the first line. What is $\,G\, V\, H\,$ for you? Union of these two subgroups or the subgroup generated by them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the commutator $[g,h]:=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$. Since both $ghg^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}$ is in $H$, $[g,h]\in H$. Similarly for $G$, thus, $[g,h]\in H\cap G=1$.

Comment: Aww that's so cute. Thanks!